# Hyperboloid Geometry Book

Tags: reference-request, analytic-geometry, book-recommendation

Which is a good and dedicated book about the geometry of a hyperboloid? Almost all geometry books seem to be on all topics and contain hyperboloid treatment only as a small part of the book.

Comment: What kind of treatment are you looking for that you couldn't find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid)?

Comment: Not looking for just a page or a few pages of reference treatment.

Comment: Yes, but what more would there be to say about the general properties of hyperboloids that you would want to know? I would say that the Wikipedia article is a reasonable complete catalogue of all of the interesting things that one might say about a hyperboloid specifically (as opposed to some more general solid of revolution). I think it's unlikely that any modern mathematician has seen fit to write an entire book (or even a chapter of a book) solely about hyperboloids.

Comment: Would you be interested in, say, a reference on algebraic geometry? The $n$-dimensional hyperboloids exist as the null sets of a particular class of degree 2 polynomials in $n$ variables, and as such hyperboloids inherit a number of more general properties of affine varieties.